# Comparing two different string formats for UTC that represents timestamp in java

Tags: java, datetime

I have a string "21-SEP-15 02.48.48.000000000 AM UTC" which represents utc timestamp and I have "2015-10-08T20:13:21.3Z" format string which represents another timestamp. How do I compare them if they are equal or not?

Comment: 1) parse the `String` to a `LocalDateTime`. 2) Use [`LocalDateTime.isEqual()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-).

Comment: As Boris has said, you can't compare them directly as `Strings` and get the chronological ordering you want.  You'll need to first convert the `Strings` into a temporal object.  The Java Date-Time API in Java 8 is well suited to this.  Once you have the strings as temporal objects, eg. `LocalDateTime` instances, you can compare them using `isEqual()` or `compareTo()`.  Since these are already UTC times, you could also directly compare their POSIX time integer values obtained from `Instant.toEpochMilli()` for chronological ordering.

Comment: @BoristheSpider could you please explain more on how I could go about doing that using LocalDateTime, how can I convert that specific format string of the timestamp to the local time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The second format uses the ISO convention so it can be parsed easily.

The first one is a bit more complicated to parse, in particular because the month is in upper case.

One way would be:

```
String ts1 = "21-SEP-15 02.48.48.000000000 AM UTC";
String ts2 = "2015-10-08T20:13:21.3Z";

DateTimeFormatter fmt1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a VV")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

Instant d1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(ts1, fmt1).toInstant();
Instant d2 = Instant.parse(ts2);
```

You can then compare the two instants with `d1.equals(d2)`.

Comment: I am currently using Java 7 and it does not support DateTimeFormatter. I tried multiple different ways using SimpleDateFormat which is the equivalent of DateTimeFormatter but failed. But yeah thank you so much for the solution above. That is exactly what I wanted to do. And also Instant is not supported.